# Nonetype into list to Integer

Tags: python

I have Nonetype objects in my string list. I want to convert this NoNetype to 0.

I tried

```
name=int([d['name'] for d in list1]or 0)
```

but it did not work.
Could you help me?Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `or 0` is not where it should be. You should operate on `d['name']`:

```
names = [int(d['name'] or 0) for d in list1]
```

But it'll also convert `''` and other `False`-like objects, not only `None`. If you want to operate on `None`s only (and thus get an exception on empty strings and other objects for which `bool` returns `False`), use an `if` expression:

```
names = [int(d['name'] if d['name'] is not None else 0) for d in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list is `list1`:

```py
list1 = [x or 0 for x in list1]
```

**Note that this will also replace "Falsy" values like `False` or `""` with 0. If you dont want that to happen**:

```py
list1 = [x if x is not None else 0 for x in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it did not work. Could you help me?Thanks

You might be getting [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) exception stating `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Even if it runs, it won't give the expected output. You need to move your `0` to somewhere else.

Try this:

```
list1 = [{ 'name' : 1000 }, None]
names = [int(d['name']) if d is not None else 0 for d in list1]
print(names)
```

Output:

```
[1000, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `None`s in the list of dicts, where each dict contains 'name' item, then you should do something like:

```py
list1 = [d['name'] or 0 for d in list1]
```

All the `None`s will become `0`s.